# 2-D line gradient color in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, colors, gradient, matlab-figure

Is it possible to add gradient color to 2-D line in Matlab, especially when you have small number of data points (less than 10?), so the result would be similar to one in image below?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not difficult if you have MATLAB R2014b or newer.

```
n = 100;
x = linspace(-10,10,n); y = x.^2;
p = plot(x,y,'r', 'LineWidth',5);

% modified jet-colormap
cd = [uint8(jet(n)*255) uint8(ones(n,1))].';

drawnow
set(p.Edge, 'ColorBinding','interpolated', 'ColorData',cd)
```

Which results in:

[image]

Excerpted from  [Undocumented Features - Color-coded 2D line plots with color data in third dimension](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731034551/http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/2383/undocumented-features/7849/color-coded-2d-line-plots-with-color-data-in-third-dimension#t=201607310345511097808). The original author was [thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2605073/thewaywewalk). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/7849). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 2383 and example ID: 7849.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 5):

Here's one possible approach: explicitly plot each segment of the line with a different color taken from the desired colormap.

```
x = 1:10; % x data. Assumed to be increasing
y = x.^2; % y data
N = 100; % number of colors. Assumed to be greater than size of x
cmap = parula(N); % colormap, with N colors
linewidth = 1.5; % desired linewidth
xi = x(1)+linspace(0,1,N+1)*x(end); % interpolated x values
yi = interp1(x,y,xi); % interpolated y values
hold on
for n = 1:N
    plot(xi([n n+1]), yi([n n+1]), 'color', cmap(n,:), 'linewidth', linewidth);
end
```

[image]