# Line plot with color gradient

Tags: idl-programming-language, line-plot

Is there a way to create a plot in IDL with a color gradient to it?  What I'm looking for is similar to [this Matlab question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174917/2-d-line-gradient-color-in-matlab).  The best I know how to do is to plot each segment of the line in a `for` loop, but this seems rather cumbersome:

```
x = float(indgen(11) - 5)
y = x ^ 2

loadct, 2, /silent
!p.background = 255
plot, x, y
for i = 0, 9 do begin
   oplot, x(i:i+1), y(i:i+1), color = i * 20, thick = 4
endfor
```

[image]

I'm using IDL 8.2 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue once and there seems to be no (simple) solution. Though I surrendered, you can try using a RGB-vector and the VERT_COLORS-keywords, provided by the [PLOT function](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/plot.html):

> A vector of indices into the color table for the color of each vertex
>   (plot data point). Alternately, a 3xN byte array containing vertex
>   color values. If the values supplied are not of type byte, they are
>   scaled to the byte range using BYTSCL. If indices are supplied but no
>   colors are provided with the RGB_TABLE property, a default grayscale
>   ramp is used. If a 3xN array of colors is provided, the colors are
>   used directly and the color values provided with RGB_TABLE are
>   ignored. If the number of indices or colors specified is less than the
>   number of vertices, the colors are repeated cyclically.

That would change the appearence more discrete, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I've avoided using the plot function in the past in favor of the subroutine, but this works perfectly: `colors = indgen(11) * 20` and `p = plot(x, y, rgb_table = 2, vert_colors = colors`.

Comment: At least in my case, I don't necessarily need a smooth gradient because I have so many points to plot, so this stair stepping is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a routine [MG_PLOTS](https://github.com/mgalloy/mglib/blob/master/src/vis/lineplots/mg_plots.pro) which can do this in direct graphics:

```
IDL> plot, x, y, /nodata, color=0, background=255
IDL> mg_plots, x, y, color=indgen(10) * 20, thick=4
```

Of course, it is just a wrapper for what you where doing manually.

[image: Multi-color line]